# Sublime -- How to create my own subfolders for custom plugins?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

My custom plugins are cluttering up my `/Packages/User` directory, and I'd like to tidy up a bit by creating different subfolders for each plugin -- e.g., `/Packages/User/0.custom_plugin_one`.  The catch-all directory for custom plugins is `/Packages/User`.  I haven't been able to locate any documentation that tells me how to create a reference to my own custom subfolders so that plugins will automatically load.  Can anyone please steer me in the right direction?

Along with the custom plugins in the user-defined directories, I'd like to include all of the related `.sublime-build` and `.sublime-keymap` files.

Comment: you can always just put them in `Packages/MyCustomPlugin0` and so on...

Comment: That worked and is an acceptable solution for my organizational OCDC complex.  I'll use the folder prefix of `0.` so that all my custom plugins are at the top of my file / folder viewer on the Mac.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins generally live in a dedicated subfolder of the `Packages` directory. If you've developed your own, you can always make directories like `Packages/0MyFirstPlugin`, `Packages/1MySecondPlugin`, etc. to keep them at the top of your directory hierarchy.

Comment: So, basically, the plug-ins won't be recognized if they're in subdirectories of `Packages/User` ?

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS Sublime 3 users, the are under:

```
/Users/yuchen21/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages/User/
```

Replace `yuchen21` with your username.